# Laravel No query results for model [App\Tag]

Tags: laravel

i am facing this error in my laravel project after i installed elqouent sluggable package....

here is my error

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. (2/2) NotFoundHttpException No query results for model [App\Tag]. in Handler.php (line 131) at Handler->prepareException(object(ModelNotFoundException)) in Handler.php (line 109) at Handler->render(object(Request), object(ModelNotFoundException)) in Handler.php (line 47) at Handler->render(object(Request), object(ModelNotFoundException)) in Pipeline.php (line 82) at Pipeline->handleException(object(Request), object(ModelNotFoundException)) in Pipeline.php (line 55) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 65) at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php (line 49) at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php (line 64) at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php (line 37) at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php (line 59) at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 102) at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php (line 576) at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php (line 535) at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php (line 513) at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php (line 174) at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 30) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php (line 30) at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php (line 30) at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27) at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46) at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 102) at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php (line 149) at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php (line 116) at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php (line 53) at require_once('/opt/lampp/htdocs/ECD-Website/public/index.php') in server.php (line 21) (1/2) ModelNotFoundException No query results for model [App\Tag]. in Builder.php (line 395) at Builder->firstOrFail() in ImplicitRouteBinding.php (line 35) at ImplicitRouteBinding::resolveForRoute(object(Application), object(Route)) in Router.php (line 648) at Router->substituteImplicitBindings(object(Route)) in SubstituteBindings.php (line 39) at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 65) at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php (line 49) at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php (line 64) at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php (line 37) at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php (line 59) at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 102) at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php (line 576) at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php (line 535) at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php (line 513) at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php (line 174) at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 30) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php (line 30) at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php (line 30) at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27) at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46) at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 53) at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php (line 102) at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php (line 149) at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php (line 116) at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php (line 53) at require_once('/opt/lampp/htdocs/ECD-Website/public/index.php') in server.php (line 21)

here is my *routes.php*

```
<?php        
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


/*
   Backend Routes
*/


/**************Dashboard********************/

Route::get('/dash','Backend\DashboardController@index');


/***********Home Page **********************/

Route::get('/dashboard', 'Backend\HomeController@index');
Route::get('/home/edit/{id}', 'Backend\HomeController@edit');
Route::get('/home/create', 'Backend\HomeController@create');
Route::post('home/create','Backend\HomeController@store');
Route::delete('/homedelete/{id}', 'Backend\HomeController@destroy');
//Route::PATCH('home/edit/{id}','Backend\HomeController@update');
//Route::delete('home/{id}',['as'=>'home.destroy','uses'=>'Backend\HomeController@destroy']);
Route::patch('home/{id}',['as'=>'home.update','uses'=>'Backend\HomeController@update']);



/*****************************Causes********************************************/
Route::get('admin/causes', 'Backend\CausesController@index');
Route::get('/admin/causes/edit/{id}', 'Backend\CausesController@edit');
Route::get('admin/causes/create', 'Backend\CausesController@create');
Route::post('admin/causes/create','Backend\CausesController@store');
Route::PATCH('admin/causes/edit/{id}','Backend\CausesController@update');
Route::patch('admin/causes/{id}',['as'=>'causes.update','uses'=>'Backend\CausesController@update']);
Route::delete('admin/causes/{id}',['as'=>'causes.destroy','uses'=>'Backend\CausesController@destroy']);



/**********************project****************************************************/
Route::get('/admin/project', 'Backend\ProjectController@index');
Route::get('/admin/project/edit/{id}', 'Backend\ProjectController@edit');
Route::get('/admin/project/create', 'Backend\ProjectController@create');
Route::post('admin/project/create',['as'=>'project.create','uses'=>'Backend\ProjectController@store']);
Route::PATCH('admin/project/edit/{id}','Backend\ProjectController@update');
Route::patch('admin/project/{id}',['as'=>'project.update','uses'=>'Backend\ProjectController@update']);
Route::delete('admin/project/{id}',['as'=>'project.destroy','uses'=>'Backend\ProjectController@destroy']);


/**********************Event*******************************************************/
Route::get('/admin/events', 'Backend\EventController@index');
Route::get('/admin/events/create', 'Backend\EventController@create');
Route::post('/admin/events/create','Backend\EventController@store');
Route::delete('admin/events/{id}',['as'=>'events.destroy','uses'=>'Backend\EventController@destroy']);
Route::get('/admin/events/edit/{id}', 'Backend\EventController@edit');
Route::PATCH('admin/events/edit/{id}','Backend\EventController@update');
Route::patch('admin/events/{id}',['as'=>'events.update','uses'=>'Backend\EventController@update']);





/**********************history*******************************************/
Route::get('/admin/about/history', 'Backend\HistoryController@index');
Route::get('/admin/about/history/create', 'Backend\HistoryController@create');
Route::post('/admin/about/history/create','Backend\HistoryController@store');
Route::delete('admin/about/history/{id}',['as'=>'history.destroy','uses'=>'Backend\HistoryController@destroy']);
Route::get('/admin/about/history/edit/{id}', 'Backend\HistoryController@edit');
Route::PATCH('admin/about/history/edit/{id}','Backend\HistoryController@update');
Route::patch('admin/about/history/{id}',['as'=>'history.update','uses'=>'Backend\HistoryController@update']);


/**********************Address******************************************/
Route::get('/admin/about/address', 'Backend\ContactController@index');
Route::get('/admin/about/address/create', 'Backend\ContactController@create');
Route::post('/admin/about/address/create','Backend\ContactController@store');
Route::delete('admin/about/address/{id}',['as'=>'contact.destroy','uses'=>'Backend\ContactController@destroy']);
Route::get('/admin/about/address/edit/{id}', 'Backend\ContactController@edit');
Route::PATCH('admin/about/address/edit/{id}','Backend\ContactController@update');
Route::patch('admin/about/address/{id}',['as'=>'contact.update','uses'=>'Backend\ContactController@update']);

Route::get('/admin/message', 'Backend\MessageController@index');
Route::delete('admin/message/{id}',['as'=>'message.destroy','uses'=>'Backend\MessageController@destroy']);




/**********************Category****************************************************/
Route::get('/admin/category', 'Backend\CategoryController@index');
Route::get('/admin/category/edit/{id}', 'Backend\CategoryController@edit');
Route::get('/admin/category/create', 'Backend\CategoryController@create');
Route::post('admin/category/create',['as'=>'category.create','uses'=>'Backend\CategoryController@store']);
Route::PATCH('admin/category/edit/{id}','Backend\CategoryController@update');
Route::patch('admin/category/{id}',['as'=>'category.update','uses'=>'Backend\CategoryController@update']);
Route::delete('admin/category/{id}',['as'=>'category.destroy','uses'=>'Backend\CategoryController@destroy']);


/**********************Tag****************************************************/
Route::get('/admin/tag', 'Backend\TagController@index');
Route::get('/admin/tag/edit/{id}', 'Backend\TagController@edit');
Route::get('/admin/tag/create', 'Backend\TagController@create');
Route::post('admin/tag/create',['as'=>'tag.create','uses'=>'Backend\TagController@store']);
Route::PATCH('admin/tag/edit/{id}','Backend\TagController@update');
Route::patch('admin/tag/{id}',['as'=>'tag.update','uses'=>'Backend\TagController@update']);
Route::delete('admin/tag/{id}',['as'=>'tag.destroy','uses'=>'Backend\TagController@destroy']);


/*********************************blog*************************************************/

Route::get('/blogs', 'Backend\BlogController@index');
Route::get('/posts/create', 'Backend\BlogController@create');
Route::get('/posts/edit/{id}', 'Backend\BlogController@edit');
Route::post('/posts/', 'Backend\BlogController@store');
Route::patch('/posts/{id}', ['as'=>'blog.update','uses'=>'Backend\BlogController@update']);

/****************************Gallery************************************************/

Route::get('gallery/list', 'Backend\GalleryController@viewGalleryList');
Route::post('gallery/save', 'Backend\GalleryController@saveGallery');
Route::get('gallery/view/{id}', 'Backend\GalleryController@viewGalleryPics');
Route::post('image/do-upload', 'Backend\GalleryController@doImageUpload');
Route::get('gallery/delete/{id}','Backend\GalleryController@deleteGallery');




 /*
      Frontend Routes
    */
    Route::get('/', 'Frontend\HomeController@index');
    Route::get('project', 'Frontend\ProjectController@index');

    Route::get('/aboutus', 'Frontend\AboutUsController@index');
    Route::post('/message/create','Frontend\MessageController@store');

    Route::get('causes', 'Frontend\CausesController@index');

    Route::get('/cause-single/{slug}', 'Frontend\CausesController@index_detail');

    Route::get('blog','Frontend\BlogController@index');

    Route::get('project-detail/{slug}', 'Frontend\ProjectController@index_detail');
    Route::get('gallery', 'Frontend\GalleryController@index');

    Route::get('event', 'Frontend\EventController@index');
    Route::get('event-detail/{slug}', 'Frontend\EventController@index_detail');
    Route::get('volunteer', function () {
        return view('frontend/volunteer');
    });
    Route::post('/volunteer/create','Frontend\VolunteerController@store');
    Route::get('Mission_&_Vision', function () {
        return view('frontend/our mission');
    });
    Route::get('project_sustainability', function () {
        return view('frontend/Project-Sustainablity');
    });

    Route::get('contactus', function () {
        return view('frontend/contactus');
    });
    Route::get('team', function () {
        return view('frontend/team');
    });
    Route::get('testimonials', function () {
        return view('frontend/testimonials');
    });

    Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'Frontend\CommentController@store');
    Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'Frontend\BlogController@show');
    Route::get('/posts/tags/{tag}', 'Frontend\TagController@index');

    Route::get('user/index', 'Backend\UserController@index');
    Route::delete('user/index/{id}',['as'=>'user.destroy','uses'=>'Backend\UserController@destroy']);

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

here is my *TagController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Tag;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class TagController extends Controller
{
public function index(Tag $tag){


//        return $tag;


    $posts=$tag->posts;


    return view('frontend.blog',compact('posts'));

}
}
```

I don't know what is causing this error...it was working just fine!  any help please? i tried changing the route name for tag and also paced the route at the top but am still facing this error...am a beginner in laravel and i cant solve this issue..

Comment: what's the url you were trying to access? It usually means that the route you were trying to access had a tag (usually identified by id), not present in your database.

Comment: /post/tags/{tag}  ... And i have 2 tags in my database and but i cant access them

Comment: Can you show us your Tag Model ?

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{

    protected $table='tags';
    protected $fillable=['name'];

    public function posts(){


        return $this->belongsToMany(Blog::class);

    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'name';
    }
}
and in my appserviceprovider public function boot()
    {
      

        view()->composer('frontend.layouts.Tag_section',function($view){

            $view->with('tags',\App\Tag::has('posts')->pluck('name'));

        });
     

        
    }

Comment: so through the browser, you are trying to access /post/tags/1? (just make sure, the database has the same value you're trying to access it with)

Comment: No its a name not an id ...post/tags/the-tag-name